# Set width of table td the same as its content

Tags: html, css

How to set width of `table td` the same as its content without changing table behavior.

I want the table to have 100% width but table td tends to expand. see image below.[image]

And then I try to add `td style = "width:120px"` and I get my wanted result for the label and input field to just as not to far away from each other,see image below. [image]
To get my wanted result, do i need to define width for `table td` or is there any simple way around without hard-coded width? so in the case I have another table with long label like `Another long label One:` ,I would not have to set another approximately 300px for it's `table td`. Any help is so much aprreciated.

see also [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmwpqznk/) demo

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like the following, to ensure the 2nd column always get the maximum width that is available.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
table td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmwpqznk/1/

Comment: or, set it on the first column `table td:first-child {width: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `width:"auto"` instead.

It will fit automatically depending on the content.

Comment: does not produce my wanted result

Answer (score 0):

If the width:"auto" did not work for you.

Try adding another pair of `<td></td>` to each of the `<tr></tr>` in the table
and add this to the CSS for example

```
table td {
min-width : 160px;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewnjfrun/1/)

Comment: ,I don't want to set a hard-coded width as you said like 160px as possible